# CakePHP customize Router URL order

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.3

I'm using CakePHP to one of my project. When I was designing the URL, I know CakePHP does well when I use

```
$this->Html->Link('Add Post', array('controller'=>'posts', 'action'=>'edit', 1234))
```

CakePHP will generate URI **/appname/posts/edit/1234**. But what I'm thinking **/appname/post/1234/edit** is better than the former one. I couldn't find a solution to workaround with it.

I've tried

```
$this->Html->Link('Add Post', array('controller'=>'posts', 1234, 'action'=>'edit'))
```

but CakePHP will ignore the order of array.

Does anyone know how to achieve this URL? Basically I don't want to modify function Router::url, what I need is to write code in my ctp view file and CakePHP to know the right order I put. How can I do that?

BTW, I'm using CakePHP 2.3.

Comment: You'll need to actually use routes - `Config/routes.php`.  There are many examples in the CakePHP book online.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a job for routing, more specifically reverse routing : http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/routing.html

In `app/Config/routes.php` you could add something along the lines of the following:

```
Router::connect(
    '/:controller/:id/:action',
    array('controller' => 'posts', 'action' => 'edit'),
    array('id' => '[0-9]+')
);
```

Here, you tell Cake to reverse route any request coming from the edit method of the posts controller by defining the order of `pre-route named parameters`. In your view, the link should be constructed like this:

```
echo $this->Html->link('Add Post', array(
    'controller' => 'posts',
    'action' => 'edit',
    'id' => 1234
));
```

Note the extra `id` parameter being passed that we assigned in `routes.php`.  The Url should look like:

```
http://appdomain.com/posts/1234/edit
```

In my humble opinion, this is considered bad practice both from a conventional and SEO standpoint.

Comment: It does work, but why it's considered as bad practice? I'm struggling to define good and beautiful restful uri? Any suggestion? Thanks in advance.

Comment: It goes against Cake's default routing order, and your are taking the post out of context by placing it's id before the method it's called with, this is not good restful uri design, some may disagree.  By looking at the uri with no knowledge of the domain resource, I would automatically assume your edit method takes another argument.

Comment: You are right, /posts/1234/edit might not consider as a good restful uri, but if I want to upload some photos on post 1234, is /upload/posts/1234 as a good restful URI?

Comment: Yes, you can't go wrong with Cake's default routing sequence, good luck!